# Is it possible to move the origin point of the global reference system?

Tags: coordinates, origin, fspy

I am using fspy add-on in order to match the render camera with a photo I took and that I want to use as background image for a building render.
This add-on requires a sort of match between a reference point you set in its preparing standalone part (fspy is composed of a standalone part and a blender add-on to import the camera settings files you get from the standalone part) and the global reference system origin inside blender.
Now, the photo I took is such that I should position the reference system origin of fspy outside the photo itself. This thing is not possible in fspy.
A solution could be that to move my entire blender scene, in order to have the global reference system origin in a position that resides within the photo I took.
Anyway my scene is quite complex, so I was guessing is it were possible, before, to move the global reference system origin.
Thank you!

Comment: Short answer: no.  You can only, as you mention, move things in reference to the global coordinate system, but you can't change it.  (Mathematically the two are equivalent, but the mechanics isn't.)

Comment: Thanks @Marty Fouts !